# Play Framework Without JPA

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I love play, But cannot use JPA for some reasons. Could someone really help me to point another alternatives for JPA?

Comment: there is not enough info here. You want an alternative to JPA but you need to at least specify what you want this alternative to do. Additionally, emt14 has say, JPA is a key feature of play, if you don't want to use JPA then play might not be the right framework for your needs.

Comment: Thanks graham, I assumed play framework may be suitable even without using JPA as I found some were using plain JDBC and many other alternatives, I never know Play might not be needed if I dont use JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA is a key feature of play. You could replace the implementation (hibernate) by another provider though. Play's features would not be as useful without JPA support.

However it is still possible to use straight JDBC within play if you need to.
I can't really work out why you should not be able to use JPA but an alternative would be ok. Maybe you should elaborate more on this.

Comment: Thanks emt.We are new to JPA so was looking for alternatives.our team mostly worked in plain JDBC and Spring JDBC template,Considering the project timelines we doesnt wanted to get into two new frameworks moreover we dont have any senior level person for us to assist in JPA. anyways thanks.

Comment: Basic JPA is fairly straighforward. If you follow the play Model you should be up and running very quickly. take look at the link which should show you how quicly and straightforward the model works. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jpa

Comment: @DarkRider - Being knew to some technology should not stop you for learn others;) Especially in this case, when JPA is over plain JDBC...

Comment: @CristianBoariu True, But on a learning curve when you need some sort of clarification or support you are left alone. anyways Am trying to get into Play Framework coz I love it.Any sworking samples will highly helpful for me. Esp working with JPA & Play on an existing domain model.

Comment: Follow the play tutorialand official documentation. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide1. It's a very good introduction. You will find the learning curve is very fast.

Comment: IMHO, getting into a new technology for a specific desired feature (e.g. hot class reloading, controller layer support) shouldn't push you to learn something else (e.g. JPA), specially when you know an alternative for it (e.g. JDBC).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JPA (use one thread for database) you can use EBEAN ORM default wich use multithread....

So with hibernate you can generate with the models you database, with EBEAN you have to improve a SQL file and evolution plugin.